# unable to activate an InfoPath form

Tags: infopath, feature

I have created an InfoPath 2013 form, uploaded it to the server. When I try to activate it I get an error in the ULS log saying "...Infopath:  could not be activated to site collection  because the user  does not have the correct permissions."
I find this error hard to understand since I am a member of the Farm Admin, and local server admin groups.

This error doesn't tell me what I don't have access to, so if anyone has an idea, I ready to listen.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be a member of ***site collection** admins* (that is different from farm admin and local server admin roles).

You can find them from site perspective:

- `<your-site-url>/_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx`
- Site settings - Site collection administrators

or from SharePoint Central Administration (if you currently don't have an admin access to *site* itself):

- Application Management - Change site collection administrators

Add there the account under which you will try to activate the form.

Comment: Thanks lehuspohus for your suggestion. However, I am also a site collections admin. Therefore, this did not help. Do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Are you trying to activate form from Central Admin or powershell? Are you sure that you are opening Central Administration to upload form under the same user as you logging in to your site? If so, more info required: ULS logs here and screenshot of checking permissions in /FormServerTemplates library on your site that you are trying to activate to. Anyway, simplest way is to try give yourself a [Full Control permission to Web application](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/08/configuring-web-application-user-policies-in-sharepoint-2013-2016.html) to be sure that permission is the issue.

Comment: Hi Lehuspohus - I was able to give myself full control in the Web Application policy and I have full control to the /FormsServerTemplates library. I am using the Central Admin not powershell to activate the form. I am using the same UID to login and activate the form.

Comment: Here is a snipit of the ULS log
12/27/2022 09:07:17.89  w3wp.exe (0x2314)                        0x0518 InfoPath Forms Services        Conversion and Deployment      m22j High     Form template Catalog Request Don.xsn (urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:Catalog-Request-Don:-myXSD-2005-10-21T21-12-27) could not be activated to site collection http://purchasing.XXXXX.dev.sos.local because the user Don Richardson does not have the correct permissions. c76486a0-c3af-9032-9b55-6bb6eee20e3d

Comment: I was able to activate the form by logging in with the user profile that created the environment. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by logging in with the user profile that created the environment.